# Odd MVC controller behaviour - parameter name clashes with model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, query-string, selectlist, viewbag

I have a controller responding to a URL like:

`http://localhost:64121/BrowseNode/Create/1016?nodeTypeId=Category`

**Bug: The `NodeTypeId` dropdown list does not select the desired element (id of 3).**

### Action method (fails to select item 3):

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix = "id")]int? parentBrowseNodeId, Enums.eNodeType? nodeTypeId)
    {
        int typeId = (int)nodeTypeId.GetValueOrDefault(Enums.eNodeType.Category);
        // 3 is hard-wired to test this bug - still does not work
        ViewBag.NodeTypeId = new SelectList(db.NodeType, "NodeTypeId", "LabelEN", 3);
        ViewBag.OwnerUserId = new SelectList(db.User, "UserId", "EmailAddress", 3);
        return View(new CreateItemVM()
        {
            OwnerUserId = 3,
            NodeTypeId = (int)nodeTypeId
        });
    }
```

If I debug the real code the `nodeTypeId` parameter has a value of "Category" which then becomes 3 but I am using hard-wired values and it still fails.

Then if I use an `int` parameter, instead of enum, with this URL:

`http://localhost:64121/BrowseNode/Create/1016?nodeTypeId=3`

### Action method with int parameter (works):

```
    // GET: /BrowseNode/Create
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Prefix = "id")]int? parentBrowseNodeId, int  nodeTypeId)
    {
        ViewBag.NodeTypeId = new SelectList(db.NodeType, "NodeTypeId", "LabelEN", 3);
        ViewBag.OwnerUserId = new SelectList(db.User, "UserId", "EmailAddress", 3);
        return View(new CreateItemVM()
        {
            OwnerUserId = 3,
            NodeTypeId = 3
        });
    }
```

### The view Create.cshtml has two drop downs like:

```
   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NodeTypeId, "NodeTypeId", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("NodeTypeId")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NodeTypeId)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OwnerUserId, "OwnerUserId", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("OwnerUserId")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OwnerUserId)
        </div>
    </div>
```

### The question:

**Why does the code work with an `int` parameter, but fail with the `enum` even when the actual selection values for the lists are hard-wired to 3?**

### Update:

This problem is purely down to using the name `nodeTypeId` as the parameter name of the enum. If I rename it to `nodetype` and change the url to `http://localhost:64121/BrowseNode/Create/1016?nodeType=Category` it works!

It looks like the parameter name is somehow being passed into the view and overriding the default. I was not aware of parameters being automatically passed to MVC views from controllers. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it is not widely publicised (or I just missed it over my many years of MVC programming), but `querystring` parameters are automatically used by at least certain controls in a view, in preference to ViewBag values of the same name.

So basically what was happening was my querystring `nodeTypeId` string parameter was taking precedence over both my `ViewBag` `SelectList`'s current value property of the same name and my `ViewModel` property of the same name.

A `DropDownList` can apparently take it's current value from the `ViewModel`, the selected property of `SelectList` (in a matching ViewBag property), or from a `querystring` parameter.

The key being that the querystring has precedence and can be used to override default value (might come in very useful).

*Ya learn something new every day* :)